# Is it true that Apple won't allow users to download full resolution photos from iCloud Photo to Windows computers?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, photos.app

I have a subscription to the 50GB iCloud Photos. It contains 50GB of my photos. I hope to back up these photos to my Windows laptop. I've downloaded iCloud for Windows and synced the photos from iCloud Photos to my Windows laptop. However, I notice a big discrepancy between the total size of the photos I downloaded and the total size of the photos on iCloud (32GB on my Windows laptop vs 50GB on iCloud). I contacted Apple Customer Support and reached a very arrogant rep. He told me that there's no way to backup the full resolution version to a PC. I need to buy a Mac to do that. Is that a nefarious sticky feature Apple uses to keep people on its ecosystem?

Comment: Report the Rep if you were unhappy with them.

Comment: @benwiggy do you know of an effective way to report an Apple rep? I’ve searched online, but the best method I found is to call Customer Service and ask to speak to a manager. I don't know what Apple will do to the rep...

Comment: I normally get a survey via email after any interaction with Apple personnel.

Comment: @benwiggy I've filled out the survey. But just feel like Apple's not going to do anything about it :(

Comment: Well, if nothing else, it's good to have a vent! I believe the support guys are graded on their customer responses, so it may affect their performance pay or promotion prospects.

Comment: IMO Google Photos is a lot nicer to use and costs the same. I've turned off Icloud entirely on the first day of buying the phone.

Comment: @JonathanReez I agree, Apple products are full of nefarious sticky features

Answer (score 45):

The iCloud for Windows app downloads the ‘most compatible’ version of the photo, which is a compressed JPEG capped to roughly 4 MP, as Windows does not by default support HEIF.

You can download the original quality from [iCloud.com/photos](https://www.icloud.com/photos/) as HEIF, by selecting some photos and choosing the down arrow at the bottom-right of the download button and choosing Unmodified Original.

[image]

[Get HEIF Image Extensions by Microsoft on the Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/heif-image-extensions/9pmmsr1cgpwg) to view HEIC photos and HEVC video on Windows 10.

macOS Photos app always uses the original quality with macOS built-in support for HEIF.

Comment: Thank you for your input. When I log into my iCloud Photos, I don’t have a drop down to choose for unmodified original. Once I click the download icon, I get the photos in a zip file

Comment: @spacenet Hover the download button, a new down arrow appears in the lower-right of the button, click that instead.

Comment: I've hovered, but no arrow or drop-down menu appears..

Comment: Which browser are each of you two using?  In any case, it seems that Apple doesn't make it as easy to get the full quality images downloaded to Windows, but it's not due to any nefarious marketing reasons, but simply because Windows does not natively support the file format.

Comment: The down arrow is really subtle and may be covered by the cursor and/or tooltip with some mouse positions. It's not the best design and is incredibly easy to miss.

Comment: @ZachLipton Thank you Zach! I found the tiny arrow :)

Comment: @grg I don't have the HEIF Image Extension, but I'm able to open HEIC on my Windows 10...

Comment: @ZachLipton given that apple is usually quite good on design and user friendliness, I am guessing this is very intentional

Comment: @htmlcoderexe more probably, the feature is not used by enough users to reach the magic Apple's threshold of 80%, so no effort is put in there. I had to turn iCloud Photos off completely, as it only works properly if you use newest Apple hardware with lots of free space (like a dozen of GiB).

Comment: Today, I was able to use this by clicking the final ... button in a circle, and there it shows me "More download options"

Answer (score -2):

and there's [this](https://imazing.com/heic) HEIC to JPEG converter from iMazing to get those 50 GB of photos to the right format.